pnpm version not getting updated even after the new version installation
I am getting this issue while trying to update pnpm to the latest version on my macOS, where I use nvm to manage different Node.js versions. Even after updating pnpm using the command pnpm add -g pnpm, the version remained stuck at 8.12.0 and did not change to the latest version.
Environment:
macOS (ARM64)
Node.js managed by nvm (currently using v20.10.0)
Path to pnpm (before any changes): /Users/shadab/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/pnpm

It happened to me on my ubuntu wsl. For whatever reason, pnpm fails (?) to find node in the $PATH and falls back to check /usr/bin/node. Just paste this for a wacky fix
sudo ln -s /home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/$(node -v)/bin/node /usr/bin/node
